# How to find which pod is using a Persistent Volume Claim in GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have several Persistent Volume Claims in Google Kubernetes Engine that I am not sure if they are still used or not. How can I find out which pod they are attached to or is safe to delete them?

Google Kubernetes UI tells me they are bound but not to which container. Or maybe it means they are bound to a Volume Claim.

kubectl describe did not return the name of the pods either.

```
   kubectl describe pv xxxxxx-id
```

[image]

Comment: See [Display which Pods have the PVC in use](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/65233)

Comment: Thank you very much. :-) you just saved some trees once I delete these unused volumes.

Answer (score 6):

this gives you the PVC for each pod

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o=json | jq -c '.items[] | {name: .metadata.name, namespace: .metadata.namespace, claimName: .spec |  select( has ("volumes") ).volumes[] | select( has ("persistentVolumeClaim") ).persistentVolumeClaim.claimName }'
```